# Asp.net Core empty .scss files in Browser

Tags: c#, google-chrome, debugging, sass, asp.net-core-mvc

I develop a **Asp.net Core MVC** WebApplication under *Visual Studio 2015*.
I m working with **Sass files** in my web Application.
To get my FrontEnd developer's life easier, I want map .css files to .scss file in my browser (Chrome).

I have added **.css** files and **.css.map** files and **.scss** sources files under **wwwroot** folder. (to be sure, it was public folder).

So my struct is

```
ProjectName
  wwwroot
    css
    sass
```

But when I open the file in my browser, it is always empty.

I have add `app.UseDirectoryBrowser();` and `app.UseStaticFiles();`in my Startup.cs file to be sure, it works.

I can see my file but when I click on it, ... nothing happends (white page).

What I have missing ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found the solution.
I need to add the correct MIME type for .scss file in Startup.cs file.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDirectoryBrowser();

        var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
        // Add .scss mapping
        provider.Mappings[".scss"] = "text/css";
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
        {
            ContentTypeProvider = provider
        });
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

rdhainaut's answer worked for me, but if you're storing your sass files in a folder outside of webroot you have to add a file provider that finds it in your app directory in the startup.cs file. I'm not sure if this would be considered a best-practice, but it is an option.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
     //do something

     app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
              Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"SassyStyles")),
                RequestPath = new PathString("/SassyStyles"),
                ContentTypeProvider = provider
            });

     //do more stuff

}
```